# How can I change the file name use c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, rename

How do I change the name of this file to only date?
For example this file:

```
[xx x]_101-rename.Main_20200323033346(133).wav
```

Is there a way to modify this  file to `20200323033346.wav`?

Comment: Of course, but you haven't tried [anything](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How to rename the file, how to find the timecode to rename it to, both or something else?